Get Downloads folder on Windows and Linux
There are some ways to get downloads folder with C# on Windows, but how to do this so that it will work on Windows and Linux? (Interface is AvaloniaUI if important.)

There is no global standard "Downloads" folder on Linux.  Many of the desktops use ~/Downloads, but that's just a convention.

@TimRoberts, but maybe there is some analog of the environment variable?

What you mean by "downloads folder"?  Usual tools such as wget and curl download to the current working directory.  You can call that . if you like.  Perhaps the idea is a Windows thing - in which case you should explain what it is, or your potential audience will be very limited (intersection of Windows and Linux developers).

No, because the name is not internationalized.  You can check for ~/Downloads, and if it doesn't exist, create it.  The folder is used by Chrome, Thunderbird, and Firefox.

Short Answer:
You can't
Many Linux systems have a Downloads folder, but that's just a convention, standard Linux has no Downloads folder at all. Tools like wget and curl download data in current working directory, while most distributions store the downloads folder in their own unique way.
The simplest option you have is to ask the user to select their download folder on Linux, here is a code snippet to help you do so:
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath(ref Guid folderid, uint dwFlags, IntPtr hToken, out IntPtr pszPath);

    static string GetDownloadsFolderPath()
    {
        Guid downloadsFolderId = new Guid("374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B");
        IntPtr pathPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

        int result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(ref downloadsFolderId, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out pathPtr);

        if (result == 0)
        {
            string path = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pathPtr);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pathPtr);
            return path;
        }
        else
        {
            // Prompt the user for their download path
        }
    }

